# Chain arp and nslookup to get hostname for each ip (Win)

Tags: windows, networking, shell, arp, nslookup

I would like to see the name of the devices when i do arp -a. As far as I understand there is no option to do it directly with arp. So I thought that maybe it is possible to do nslookup for every ip retrieved.
I don't know much about the shell, I just thought that I could use the pipeline operator

```
arp -a | nslookup
```

but it yelds this:

```
> > Unrecognized command: Interfaccia: 192.168.176.1 --- 0x5        
> Unrecognized command:   Indirizzo Internet    Indirizzo fisico      Tipo        
> Unrecognized command:   192.168.176.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     statico  
> Unrecognized command:   224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     statico
> Unrecognized command:   224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     statico
```

apparently it gets passed as a string. Is it possible to use a for loop, maybe?

I have seen these:
[Get hostname from MAC address on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1083899/get-hostname-from-mac-address-on-windows)

[Trouble resolving hostnames with arp -a](https://superuser.com/questions/927066/trouble-resolving-hostnames-with-arp-a)

but they seem to suggest to do nslookup manually for the IPs of interest, or to use nmap.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: you need to extract the IP addresses from arp's output first and use them as input for the nslookup command. You do know that arp does only cash IPs within your LAN (nothing "behind" your router), right?

Comment: I guessed that's what I should do, but I don't know how to "slice" the result, can you help me? Yes, I just want my local network IPs and names.

Comment: Then this is the wrong question, you need to ask how to handle the output and input of the pipe command. The "problem" has nothing to do with networking. I would suggest creating another question or editing this one. I use different tools for this type of problem (usually an ip scanner with host resulution)...

Comment: on any proper shell you would simply use `cut` :)

Answer (score 1):

##### Answer

I was looking into the same thing. There's a powershell equivalent called `Get-NetNeighbor`. Here's something you can paste into powershell that'll do what you want.

```
# Equivalent to ARP
Get-NetNeighbor -AddressFamily IPv4 | %{

    # For each arp entry, get the address and resolve its hostname
    $entry = @{
        IPAddress=$_.IPAddress;
        Hostname=(Resolve-DnsName -QuickTimeout $_.IPAddress 2>null).Namehost;
    }

    # Pack the results into a PS Object for cleaner workable output
    new-object psobject -property $entry;
}
```

---

##### Explanation

Breaking this down to its pieces:

- **Get-NetNeighbor**: this is your equivalent to ARP but since it's a powershell object its output is easier to work with.
- **$entry**: a custom object that will hold the ip address and hostname.
- **Resolve-DnsName**: this is the equivalent to nslookup though not as quick, I use the -QuickTimeout flag
- **2>null**: equivalent to the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` flag, which will make it so if there's no hostname we won't get an error for it.
- **new-object psobject**: This is what $entry gets packed into for cleaner workable output.

---

##### Example

Result of running the command as-is:

```
> Get-NetNeighbor -AddressFamily IPv4 | %{
>>     # For each arp entry, get the address and resolve its hostname
>>     $entry = @{
>>         IPAddress=$_.IPAddress;
>>         Hostname=(Resolve-DnsName -QuickTimeout $_.IPAddress 2>null).Namehost;
>>     }
>>     # Pack the results into a PS Object for cleaner workable output
>>     new-object psobject -property $entry;
>> }

IPAddress       Hostname
---------       --------
224.0.0.22      igmp.mcast.net
224.0.0.2       all-routers.mcast.net
224.0.0.22      igmp.mcast.net
224.0.0.2       all-routers.mcast.net
255.255.255.255
239.255.255.250
224.0.0.252
224.0.0.251
224.0.0.22      igmp.mcast.net
224.0.0.2       all-routers.mcast.net
10.0.0.255
10.0.0.118
10.0.0.100      tools.localhost
10.0.0.79
10.0.0.60
10.0.0.28
10.0.0.15
10.0.0.1
239.255.255.250
224.0.0.251
224.0.0.22      igmp.mcast.net
224.0.0.2       all-routers.mcast.net
```

From here you can use `where {}` or `select-string` etc for more specific results.